# Parent/child Invoice logic issue

Tags: knockout.js, parent-child

I'm stuck on a parent/child situation with Knockout.  I have a table created from a list of data (Invoices and details).  I need to have specific actions occur when some checkboxes in the table are checked.

Currently I have much of it working when the boxes are checked.  But only one of a few goals are working when the checkboxes are un-checked.  I haven't been able to figure out how to get this working.

Below is a screenshot of my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kahanu/ew6k89qv/18/).

[image: jsfiddle]
<sub>(source: [kingwilder.com](http://www.kingwilder.com/images/jsfiddle-payment-use-credit-functionality.png))</sub>

**Objective**

When either or both "Use Credit" checkboxes are **checked**:

- Disable the "Applied" inputs for the invoice and detail items in the current context - **currently working**
- Place the total Amount Due (credit amount) from any and all checked boxes in the top Amount input as a positive value - **currently working**
- Disable the radios (check, credit card, other)- **currently working**

When either or both "Use Credit" checkboxes are **UN-checked**:

- Enable the "Applied" inputs for the invoice and detail items in the current context - ***not working***
- Remove only the current context's checked amount due from the top Amount input - **currently working**
- Enable the radios - ***not working***

Any help is appreciated.  This is my working jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kahanu/ew6k89qv/18/)

This is the code that currently does the updates to the UI when a checkbox is checked:

```
self.SelectedItems.subscribe(function(datalist){
  //console.log(ko.toJSON(item));
  var totalAmountSelected = 0;

  console.log("selected list: " + self.SelectedItems().length + " - datalist: " + datalist.length);

  ko.utils.arrayForEach(datalist, function(node){
    totalAmountSelected += parseFloat(node.amountdue() * -1);
    node.Disable(true);
    node.Parent.Disable(true);
    self.Disable(true);
  });

  self.Amount(totalAmountSelected);

});
```

There's too much code to show here so please see the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose an approach that uses a boolean observable bound to your checkboxes in combination with a `ko.computed` to collect all checked details.

Currently, you're trying to add each value of the checked "use credit" boxes to an array.

In this approach, each detail has a `useCredit` observable that is either `true` or `false`. In the parent view model, there's a computed array computes if there's at least one detail that has `useCredit() === true`.

### Implementation:

In `Detail`:

```
self.useCredit = ko.observable(false);
```

With the use credit checkbox bound like so:

```
<td>
  <div data-bind="visible: amountdue() < 0" class="usecredit">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useCredit" /> Use Credit
  </div>
</td>
```

The `disable` data-bind in the other input can be bound directly to the negated `useCredit` value: `data-bind="disable: !useCredit()"`

Now, the computed chain all the way to the `payment` viewmodel starts. In `Invoice`, you compute a `useCredit` property based on all the details:

```
self.useCredit = ko.computed(function() {
  return self.details().some(function(detail) {
    return detail.useCredit();
  })
});
```

Almost the same code can be used in `payment`:

```
self.useCredit = ko.computed(function() {
  return self.invoices().some(function(invoice) {
    return invoice.useCredit();
  })
});
```

You can now bind the disable attribute of the radio buttons to either `useCredit` or you can rename it to `Disable`.

Here's these changes implemented in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qLrgb9bs/

---

P.S. If I were you, I'd remove the change event data-binds and use subscriptions/computeds.

Comment: This is close.  I like your idea for the useCredit computed to handle the disable status, I just had to reverse the value of the data bound property.  Your solution loaded the form with the detail inputs disabled, when they should be enabled and only disabled when the check box is checked.  Also the reason I used the array for the check boxes was to gather the amount due and total all selected to put in the top amount field, which is not done now.  I'll see if I can refactor your code for what I need.

Comment: If you replace the `some` with a `filter`, the computeds will return an array of details/invoices that have `useCredit` set to true. Like so: (https://jsfiddle.net/guq85cc5/)

Comment: I like your new fiddle.  The disable states we still not correct on load, but I fixed that and with a little tweaking made it all work.  The values you had going into the top amount field were the sum of the details, when it had to be the amount due.  Easy change. Here's the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kahanu/3kvpx7xe/3/).  Thanks for the help.  You saved me.